# Kubernetes Ingress redirect setup

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, avi

I have a avi Kubernetes ingress and want to redirect / to /ui . Is it possible to do on Ingress routing rules.

poc.xxx.com/ --> How to redirect it to poc.xxx.com/ui

poc.xxx.com/ui --> ui-service

poc.xxx.com/backend --> backend-service

My ingress Yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: poc-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: poc.xxx.com
      http:
       paths:
       - path: /ui
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
            name: ui-service
            port: 
             number: 443
       - path: /backend
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
             number: 443
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you do something like this, any request at `/` will get moved to `ui` service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: poc-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: poc.xxx.com
      http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
            name: ui-service
            port: 
             number: 443
       - path: /backend
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
             number: 443
```

However still if you are looking for a redirect solution you can follow below option

Add this annotation in ingress :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~ / {
         rewrite / https://test.example.com/ui permanent;
      }
```

if request comes at `/` it will get redirected to another domain or `ui` path as you wish.

You can also create the two ingress looks like this, first one check `backend` and `/` while another one handles `ui` :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: poc-ingress
  annotation:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location ~ / {
         rewrite / https://test.example.com/ui permanent;
      }
spec:
  rules:
    - host: poc.xxx.com
      http:
       paths:
       - path: /backend
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
             number: 443
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ui-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: poc.xxx.com
      http:
       paths:
       - path: /ui
         pathType: Prefix
         backend:
           service:
            name: ui-service
            port: 
             number: 443
```

Do not forget to use the ingress class annotation in ingress.

Comment: I have been using the first method but it redirects to homepage of apache.

Comment: Also i am using avi ingress not nginx.forgot to mention that